# $_GET not working in jQuery select2

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I got a strange situation. Below are **select2** code.

```
$("#tags").select2({
    multiple: true,
    placeholder: "Please enter tags",
    tokenSeparators: [',', ' '],
    initSelection : function (element, callback) {
        var data = [];
        $(element.val().split(",")).each(function () {
            data.push({id: this, text: this});
        });
        callback(data);
    },
    ajax: {
        multiple: true,
        url: "fetch.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        type: "POST",
       data: function(term, page) {
                        return {
                            term: term
                              };
                    },
                    results: function(data, page) {
                        return {results: data};
                    }, 
    },
```

And here is php file **fetch.php**

```
$search = strip_tags(trim($_GET['term']));
```

Problem is $search didn't have any value. I checked **var_dump($_GET)** but no value is there. It is showing null.

I checked in Firebug and found post is working fine, but for some reason it is not showing in $_GET.

Screen shot attached below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're POSTing the variables, not sending them as querystring.

Var_dump $_POST and you'll find them.

Comment: What a silly mistake i have done. Thanks. Sometimes we didn't see the small things. Anyways i corrected that. Your answer is correct. Voted up. Will accept answer. in few min